# How do I get gnome-terminal to restore its title after ssh?

Tags: gnome-terminal, title-bar

I'm running gnome-terminal set to update its title according to terminal commands updating their own titles (default on Fedora 13). When I SSH to somewhere else the title is updated correctly, but then SSH exits and gnome-terminal is indicating that I'm still logged in remotely. This is confusing when trying to navigate around. How do I maintain the behaviour when logging in, and restore the old title when logging out (by default just "Terminal", but better yet display current location)?

Comment: Which shell are you using on the local side?

Comment: Don't have access right now, pretty sure it's bash though - whatever is default for gnome-terminal on Fedora 13.

Comment: I fixed it using a few wrappers commands to ssh and su:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341277/112190

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the set-title escape sequences to your shell's rc file. For `bash` v4, this would be:

```
if [[ $TERM == xterm* ]]; then
    # This puts "user@host workdir" into the titlebar.
    # (look for section "PROMPTING" in bash's manual)
    title='\u@\h \w'

    PS1+="\[\e]0;$title\007\]"
fi
```

in your **`~/.bashrc`**.

---

**Stop reading here unless you like messing with `bash` scripts.**

The code above is actually a greatly simplified version of my `~/.bashrc` snippet:

```
case $TERM in
[xkE]term*|rxvt*|cygwin)
    title_seq='\e]0;%s\007';;
screen*)
    # only set the "screen"window title
    title_seq='\ek%s\e\\';;
esac

# Very useful for: title syslog && tailf /var/log/syslog
title() { [ "$title_seq" ] && printf "$title_seq" "$*"; }

# Modify the prompt string.
if [ "$title_seq" ]; then
    title='\u@\h \w'
    PS1+="\[$(printf "${title_seq//\\/\\\\}" "$title")\]"
fi
```

---

Actually, that was my *old* `~/.bashrc` snippet. Upon discovering `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1` I had to replace the `$PS1` modification (the last `if` statement) with:

```
update_title() {
    title "$USER@$HOSTNAME ${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="update_title"
```